# How to declare functions with unique datatypes whereas variables can have multiple datatypes?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a declaration problem - or better a problem in understanding Typescript. The following situation:

```
public migrationSource: Skater | Rink;
public migrationDestination: Skater | Rink;

public migrationMode: MigrationMode;

ngOnInit() {
    this.migrationSource = this.migrationMode == MigrationMode.Skater ? new Skater() : new Rink()
    this.migrationDestination = this.migrationMode == MigrationMode.Skater ? new Skater() : new Rink()
}

migrateSkater(skater1:Skater, skater2:Skater) {
    ...
}

migrateRink(rink1:Rink, rink2:Rink) {
    ...
}
```

So far so good. But when I try now to call the function in my Angular code:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="migrationMode == mode.SKATER">
    <button (click)="migrateSkater(migrationDestination, migrationSource)">
        ...
    </button>
</ng-container> 

<ng-container *ngIf="migrationMode == mode.RINK">
    <button  (click)="migrateRink(migrationDestination, migrationSource)">
        ...
    </button>
</ng-container>
```

The following error message appears:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Skater | Rink' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Skater'.
Type 'Rink' is not assignable to type 'Skater'.
```

I understand the meaning of this error message, but I don't know how to fix it. Until today I changed the datatypes of `migrateSkater` and `migrateRink` to `any` but this is not the real I want to do. Is there a way to "clear" define the datatypes of the functions in Typescript and how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using classes and inheritance:

```
class Whole {
  public name: string;
};

class Skater extends Whole {
  public nrOfWheels: number;
}

class Rink extends Whole {
  public nrOfNuts: number;
}
```

Now you can use a function that accepts the parent class of Skater or Rink

```
  migrateWhole(w1:Whole, w2: Whole){

  }
```

In the child classes you can add functions for (deep) copying stuff.

Comment: Thx, but unfortunately this would be in more or less the same as using `any` :-(

Comment: Then I do not understand the question correctly. I'll watch the thread to see what the solution is ;-)

Comment: Well, the issue is that `Skater` and `Rink` need to process custom functions of their classes which are processed in the corresponding `migrate...` functions that cannot be part of `Whole`

Comment: I've added functions to my the example. If the custom functions are also available in the parent class, you can use inheritance to override them in the child class. I hope this makes sense. I've made an very small example in Stackblitz, where you can see in the console what the effect is.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ujh4nl?file=src/app/app.component.ts